# Popup displayed wherever i clicked on a anchor tag inside a div

Tags: html, css

Just a basic question.

I have an anchor tag like this,

```
<div><a onclick="openModal();">Popup</a></div>
```

On click i am displaying a modal. Nothing problem in this. But, since the div is a block level element, wherever i am clicking within this div(Means till the end of the div), my modal is displaying. I need to restrict this action to be bound only on click on the text "**Popup**"

I know by giving a width to this div will certainly solve this issue. Is there any work around for this other than setting a static width to the div?

I tried giving display: inline-block to the anchor tag. But no clue.

Thanks,

Comment: is the anchor tag given `display:block?` Have you set the div to something other than `display:block`? Change the div out for a `span`?

Comment: @Paulie_D1: I have not given any display css to the div. If i need to change that div to span, then i may incur many alignment issues, since there are lot many popups in the application.

Comment: If the div is set to display block, set the a href to display inline:block and it should work

Answer (score 0):

There must be a css property `display:block` attached to that particular anchor tag. Can you provide us your code snippet along with css? A fiddle will work.

Comment: I have attached a display: inline-block property to the div. It works now. Thank you :)

Comment: No need to css. Just given this line to my div. Display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `<a>` tags are inheriting some styling from within you application. Usually `display:block;` or `display: inline-block;` which is causing them to take up the full width and height of their parent `div`

You should apply `display: inline;` to the elements where you only want the text to trigger the popup.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KGs6/1/)**